# Multiple databases in MS Access VBA?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba

This Microsoft [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/113701) details how to run a query on another database than the current one used by the Access project. However it only states how to connect to DBase, Foxpro, Paradox, BTrieve and ODBC.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
UPDATE MSSQLDatabase.Table
    SET MSSQLDatabase.Table.Column = AccessDatabase.Table.Column
    WHERE MSSQLDatabase.Table.Column = AccessDatabase.Table.ID

INSERT INTO AccessDatabase.Table
    VALUES (AccessDatabase.Table.ID)
```

Can you give me any pointers of where to begin? The database I want to connect to is a SQL Server 2008 Provider Native connection. I'm using Access 2007.

To do this in VBA would be perfect.

Comment: Any reason why you cannot link the SQL Server table?

Comment: @Remou I guess not, hadn't heard of linked tables before - can you elaborate a little? (Maybe you could modify your answer) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution allows to catch errors:

```
Private Sub Command10_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err1:
        Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
        Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
        With cn
            .Provider = "SQL Native Client"
            .ConnectionString = "Server=myserver\myinstance;Database=mydb;Uid=myuser;Pwd=mypass;]"
            .Open
        End With

        MsgBox "Connection successful!"
        cn.Close
        Exit Sub

    Err1:
        MsgBox Err.DESCRIPTION
End Sub
```

The only thing to note, is that within the Visual Basic Editor, you must first go to `Tools > References`, and check `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.x Library`.

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way to work with SQL Server in MS Access is to use [linked tables](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-or-link-to-sql-server-data-HA010200494.aspx). However, you can also run [pass-through queries](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303968) and refer to a connection in-line:

```
SELECT * FROM [ODBC;FILEDSN=Z:\Docs\Test.dsn;].table_1
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM 
  [ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=srvr;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=Test;].table_1
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM [ODBC;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=svr;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=yes;].table_1
```

see also http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Comment: I do not have available, nor want to use an ODBC connection.

Comment: I should add that ODBC is the recommended way to work with SQL Server. OleDB will soon be unsupported ( http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/microsoft-sql-server-codename-denali )

Comment: I do not have the facility to use an ODBC connection. It is on a customer's server, which I do not have such access to. I don't want to use OleDB either - I want to use Provider Native.

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server Native Client? "All appropriate registry settings for the SQL Server Native Client OLE DB provider and the SQL Server Native Client **ODBC driver** are made as part of the installation process." -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131321.aspx

Comment: I believe that is to be able to create an ODBC connection to SQL Native. I want to directly connect with SQL Native. I may be able to just use the connection string directly in there though. I'll try.

Comment: I tried both a SQL Native connection string, as well as this OleDB connection string: `Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=myserver\myinstance;Database=mydatabase;Uid=myusername;
Pwd=mypassword;` - both come up with this error when I make a new query and hit Run: `Could not find installable ISAM`

Comment: Look at the link I provided in my answer for linking tables. You should be able to connect a table from SQL Server using the SQL Server Native Client (if it is configured) and from there you can run your queries as if the SQL Server table was a local Access table, with just a few differences.

Comment: ... also, do you have a system dsn? Have you checked the name of your divers?

Comment: The linked tables option requires an ODBC connection/.dsn file to be created. Ideally the connection string should be configurable rather than doing this. I just got the following query to work: `SELECT * from [ODBC;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=myserver\myinstance;Database=mydatabase;Uid=myusername;Pwd=mypassword;].myschema.mytable` - note Client 10.0, not 11.0 - 11.0 comes up with "ODBC connection failed". Is there any way to get OleDB to work? I understand it's a lot faster than ODBC. Thanks!

Comment: Not unless you want to run under VBA & ADO, which is a lot slower than linked tables. Note also that ODBC is the recommended option (see my earlier comments). There are as many connections strings as there are systems. No one who is not using your system can tell you the right one for you.

Comment: Well with the above query, that isn't using linked tables. That's just a pure SQL query. The query will actually run from VBA anyway, in a large loop on a button click; so using VBA is not an issue.